# Почему в обработчике событий не выполняется блок If?

Tags: события, c#

```
private void Combobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsInCheckBox.IsEnabled = true;
        IsStuffCheckBox.IsEnabled = true;
        if (Combobox1.Text == "Машина")
        {
            CompTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            CompTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            NameTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            NameTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            LastNameTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            LastNameTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            InviteTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            InviteTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }
        else if (Combobox1.Text == "Человек")
        {

        }
    }
```

Почему не выполняется условие If, хотя в Combobox'е выбираю "Машина".

Но если выбираю в combobox сначала "Машина", а потом выбираю "Человек", то отображаются формы по коду в if (Combobox1.Text == "Машина").
Очень странно.

Если добавить эту строку в Combobox1_SelectionChanged? То никогда не выводит формы, даже при Машина-->Человек.

Comment: исключения какие-нибудь бросает?

Comment: Нет, Исключений никаких нет.

Comment: 1. Исключений нет, в смысле программу не выбивает, или исключений нет в окне Autos?
2. Проверьте ветку "Человек" -- возможно вы просто сделали копипасту из "Машины"?
3. "Выбираю" подразумевает "Тыкаю мышкой в комбобокс" или "Оно уже выбрано при запуске формы, но ничего не происходит" ?

Comment: if (Combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Машина") - нужно было использовать верное свойство - все заработало